# Scale SVG to container when used in `background-image`

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to use an SVG as background on a container.
This background should stretch to cover whole container, no need to keep aspect ratio.
Just all the edges of the svg should align with the container edges.

I look through other questions and tried adding:

In svg

`preserveAspectRatio="none"` with `viewbox="0 0 1200 638"`

In css

`background-size: 100% 100%;`

[Heres link to example on codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cache-r2h77r)

Given the code from the sandbox above what should I do to enable the described behaviour of background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

> Note: Background sizing for vector images that lack intrinsic dimensions or proportions is not yet fully implemented in all browsers. Be careful about relying on the behavior described above, and test in multiple browsers to be sure the results are acceptable.

Add width="1200px" height="637px" to your SVG and you should be golden.

Comment: Adding explicit dimensions to SVG enabled background scaling. 
Thank you for your answer